# Starting QGIS processing algorithms from .bat-file

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, batch, bat

I have written multiple Python scripts within the QGIS 2.18 processing framework to process a sequence of tasks. What I am trying to achieve now is to call the python scripts from a `.bat`-file without opening QGIS 2.18. The `.bat`-file is executed within a Windows 10 cmd window.

I have already tried multiple things with an easy Python script which just prints `"Hello QGIS!"`. But I cannot get it to work correctly. It does not print `"Hello QGIS!"` into my cmd console window or into the file.

I have first tried it with a standalone installation of QGIS2.18 but as this wasn't working, I followed the advice from @wondim and installed QGIS2.18 over the OSGeo4W installer.
I downloaded the OSGeo4W (64-Bit version) installer from this site https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/. I double-clicked the downloaded setup file (called osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe), checked "advanced installation"->Next. On the following pages, I left the default options checked and just clicked "Next" until I got to the page where I need to select the packages I want to install. I expanded the "Desktop" drop-down menu and I see that all options are on "Skip". Now I am checking the 2.18.0-1 version (qgis-full-rel-dev) and click next. [image] As of my understanding, QGIS2.18 should now get installed via OSGeo4W installer. But if I do this, it installs QGIS3 and Python3 because there are certain dependencies. After the installation, I have QGIS3 installed and in the OSGeo4W folder is the Python37 folder (which is not the correct python folder, I need Python27).

So, with help of the OSGeo4W installer, I installed some libs which I believe where needed to generate the Python27 folder. The libs I installed are called `python-six`, `python-future` and `pyqt4`.
[image]
[image]

I have created a `.bat`-file named `launch.bat` which includes the following lines (updated following @wondim's answer):

```
REM Change OSGEO4W_ROOT to point to the base install folder
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
SET QGISNAME=qgis-rel-dev
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%
REM Gdal Setup
set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal\
REM Python Setup
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%QGIS%\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%

REM Launch python job
python "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/hello_qgis.py"
pause
```

And my hello world python script looks like this (updated following @wondim's answer):

```
import sys

# Add the path to Processing framework
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-rel-dev/python/plugins')
filename = "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/logging/log.txt"

def write_log_message(message, tag, level):
    with open(filename, 'a') as logfile:
        logfile.write('{tag}({level}): {message}'.format(tag=tag, level=level, message=message))

from qgis.core import *  # This is where the error appears
        
QgsMessageLog.instance().messageReceived.connect(write_log_message)

# Initialize QGIS Application
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-rel-dev", True)

# This line causes QGIS to crash without any error message
# app = QgsApplication([], True) 

QgsApplication.initQgis()


# Import and initialize Processing framework
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

print 'Hello QGIS!'
write_log_message("Hello QGIS\n", 'hey', 1)
```

When I am executing the launch.bat, I get the following output in my command line window:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>REM Change OSGEO4W_ROOT to point to the base install folder    
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W    
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>SET QGISNAME=qgis-rel-dev    
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>SET QGIS=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-rel-dev    
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-rel-dev    
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>REM Gdal Setup    
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>set GDAL_DATA=C:\OSGeo4W\share\gdal\    
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>REM Python Setup    
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>set PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-rel-dev\bin;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0;C:\BigData\hadoop-2.9.1;C:\BigData\hadoop-2.9.1\bin;C:\BigData\hadoop-2.9.1\sbin;    
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>SET PYTHONHOME=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27    
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>set PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-rel-dev\python;    
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>REM Launch python job

C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>python "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/hello_qgis.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/hello_qgis.py", line 11, in <module>
    from qgis.core import *
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-rel-dev\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-rel-dev\python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 24, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtCore

C:\Users\myuser\Desktop>pause
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

It seems like it is trying to import PyQt5 things, but I thought QGIS 2 is using PyQt4 or am I wrong here?

Have I forgotten to install some more Python27 related libs?

I would like to solve this by using a standalone installation of QGIS 2.18 if this is possible.

---

I wasn't successful installing QGIS2.18 via the OSGeo4W installer following this tutorial: https://www.giscourse.com/install-qgis-through-osgeo4w/ It always installs QGIS3 and Python37 by default. I have to install some libs in addition for it to generate the Python27 folder. But that does not change the fact that it does not install QGIS2.18.

---

Under "Desktop": I marked the 2.18.0 version as this is the last released version von QGIS2.18. Furthermore, under "Libs", I have installed the `python-six: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities` and `pyqt4:Python binding for Qt4` packages. Now I have the Python27 package in my OSGeo4W/apps/ folder (and the Python37 folder too).

[image: installation]

Comment: Why the QGIS 2?

Comment: @Taras Because the python scripts are not working with the new Python (5 I believe) framework which is used with QGIS 3.x

Comment: Do you have only Python 2.x installed on your machine? Which version exactly? Try to add `PYTHONPATH=` into the *"launch.bat"*.

Comment: I have Python27 installed. In which why should I add the PYTHONPATH? The python27 folder is located at: C:\Program Files\qgis\apps\Python27

Comment: I am not a QGIS expert but I would try to write "Hello QGIS!" into a txt file. It might be a `pipe` problem.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here is the order of where you wrote `sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/python/plugins')`. This code should fix the latest issue.

```
import sys

sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/python/plugins')

filename = "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\logging\log.txt"

def write_log_message(message, tag, level):
    with open(filename, 'a') as logfile:
        logfile.write('{tag}({level}): {message}'.format(tag=tag, level=level, message=message))

from qgis.core import *
QgsMessageLog.instance().messageReceived.connect(write_log_message)

# Initialize QGIS Application
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis", True)

# Line 8 causes QGIS to crash without any error message
# app = QgsApplication([], True) 

QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Add the path to Processing framework

# Import and initialize Processing framework
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

print 'Hello QGIS!'
write_log_message("Hello QGIS\n", 'hey', 1)
```

Edit:
QGIS 2 uses PyQt4 so you have to remove pyqgis 3 from OSGEO4W.

Comment: I will try it out immediately, thank you so very much!

Comment: (1/2) I tried your answer, but had to alter some paths as they where not exactly matching with mine: 1: QGISNAME=qgis-rel-dev; 2: PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37

Comment: I also altered the hello_qgis.py script so it would write "hello qgis!" to a file. But neither does the execution of the bat file cause the creation of the file nor does it write "hello qgis" to the file or the command line output.

Comment: So are you using QGIS 3? Because QGIS 2.18 only use Python 2.7.

Comment: No I am using QGIS2.18, but your PYTHONHOME path lead me to a Python37 folder. My Python27 folder is stored directly in C:\. I will try it again with PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27

Comment: The problem still remains even with PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27

Comment: In %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps do you have Python27 or Python37?

Comment: In %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps (which is C:\OSGeo4W\apps\) there is a Python37 folder

Comment: Could you send the link from which you downloaded the QGIS 2.18 installer?

Comment: Sure! I downloaded the QGIS-OSgeo4W-2.18.28-2-Setup-x86.exe from https://qgis.org/downloads ; The download link: https://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.18.28-2-Setup-x86.exe

Comment: This installer installs in C:/programs fie. Did you install  OSGeo4W Network Installer https://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/osgeo4w-setup-x86.exe ? And install QGIS through it?

Comment: I have installed that too I think. What is the right way to install QGIS so I can launch the scripts via bat file? I will uninstall all and reinstall the right thing if this is needed!

Comment: Your OGeo4W QGIS must be QGIS3.x. That is why `OSGeo4W_pygis.bat` is using Python 37.

Comment: So should I install QGIS 2.18 via the osgeo4w-setup-x86.exe following this tutorial https://www.giscourse.com/install-qgis-through-osgeo4w/ ?

Comment: Yes, as you want your code to be in Python 2.7.

Comment: Following the tutorial and installing QGIS2.18 via the OSGeo4W network, I again have the Python37 folder in C:\OSGeo4W\apps folder. (have a look in my updated question; UPDATE2)

Comment: Check this solution. https://anitagraser.com/2019/03/03/stand-alone-pyqgis-scripts-with-osgeo4w/

Comment: Hey, I finally managed to install QGIS2.18 with the Python27 folder in the OSGeo4W/apps/ folder. I believe the bat file is now running the python script. But I am getting an error. Please have a final look at my updated answer, maybe you know the solution on this too? And is the bat file actually executing the python script?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: I tried out your updated answer but I still have the same error message: ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtCore . Why PyQt5? I thought QGIS 2 is using PyQt4? Please have a look at my updated question!

Comment: That is right. QGIS 2 uses PyQt4 so you have to remove pyqgis 3 from OSGEO4W.

Comment: Hey again, can you send me a proper download link? I have again deinstalled OSGEO4W and want to install it correctly this time. And what do I have to check during the installation via OSGeo4W?

Comment: I tried to install QGIS2.18 via OSGeo4W installer but it seems to be impossible. It says that is has to install some packages for fulfilling dependencies and in the end, it install QGIS3 and Python37 libs. Maybe there is a other solution using a standalone installation of QGIS2.18?

Comment: The other option is to try it in another operating system like Ubuntu. Because, that way, you have more control.

Comment: isn't there a other solution? I will have to accomplish this with windows

Comment: What is limiting you from running your plugin from QGIS interface?

Comment: nothing, but the thing is: I have a process which includes calling a bunch of plugins in a specific order + calling the reprojectLayer (processing algorithm) and NNJoin plugin and so on.. and I want to automate this process so that I have only to double click the bat file and the process is done automatically without me needing a lot of time to manually execute each step.

Comment: You can create a plugin or just a code that runs in QGIS. QGIS can execute a Python file. Just write your code, then open QGIS python console and open the file and run it.